# Geocoded doesn't returns postal code

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I got issue with postal code. I use `CLGeocoder` and `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:` method. Everything looks fine, except that in placemark I don't have postal code. It's `nil` . I double checked location object and place mark - everything is ok and correct. Can somebody clarify this issue for me? Does geocoder return postalcode only for some countries(USA, UK, etc)? Here is the code:

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
CLLocation *currentLocation = self.locationManager.location;
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks firstObject];
            if (placemark.postalCode) {
                NSLog(@"%@", placemark.postalCode);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"No postal code");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error occurred");
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CLGeocoder doesn't return the postalCode for just a City, because there are multiple postalCode.

To obtain the postalCode, you need to be more specific like for example writing the street.

Comment: It get's the street and exact location. But it still doesn't get the postcode

Answer (score 2):

The `currentLocation` that you reverse geocode has a certain horizontal accuracy. If the location uniquely specifies a street, but this street has within the horizontal accuracy 2 postal codes assigned, none might be returned.
So, I suggest to check the `currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy` property.